# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload not working for laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, blueimp, image-upload

i am using , https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload plugin for image upload using ajax call in laravel 5. i also refered article http://peterjolson.com/using-laravel-and-jquery-file-upload/. but i am getting  the following error error

- GET http://localhost:8000/...../server/php/ 500 (Internal
  Server Error)

when i use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin i get the same error. Can anyone help with this or please suggest any working image uploader with ajax call for laravel 5

Comment: error is obtained in console

Comment: Did you find any solution ? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a main.js file, you need to adjust the url there according to the path you store it:

```
url: '../../uploadimage/server/php/'
```